# VBA connect to protected database, error handling

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba, runtime-error

I'm doing a form with two fields, one with I can browse the path for a database and the other for the database password.

Everything working fine when it the right password and a path to a database file.

My problem is an error stop the program if I dont have the right password or the file is not a database. I'm not able to test the connection without crashing.

How can I test the path and the password without making the whole thing crash. Here a look of what I have done so far(very simple) :

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim canConnect As Boolean

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & Me.txt2   & ";   Data Source=" & Me.txt1 & ";"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

If cn.State = adStateOpen Then
  canConnect = True
  cn.Close
End If

MsgBox canConnect
```

As you can see txt1 et txt2 are my two textarea and like I said everything crash before my message box prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you may need to do is add an error handler.  I eliminated the `ADODB.Recordset` because you only need the `.Connection`.

```vb
Public Sub test17()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim canConnect As Boolean
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    canConnect = False ' make it explicit, but not really needed
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & Me.txt2 & _
        ";Data Source=" & Me.txt1 & ";"
    Debug.Print strConnect
    cn.Open strConnect

    ' if we got to this point, there was no error ...
    ' which means the connection succeeded
    canConnect = True
    cn.Close

ExitHere:
    MsgBox canConnect
    Set cn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure test17"
    'MsgBox strMsg or Debug.Print strMsg, if desired
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```